# Avoid method being recalled before previous execution finished

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use a webservice to post data to an external database.
The webservice usually takes approximately 2-6 seconds to finish execution.
In the same method I also insert the record in my own database.

Now, to avoid inserting duplicates I check before I use the method, if the record already exists in my own database.

But what happens is that the webservice sometimes keeps hanging for a few minutes and then inserts the record, and when the user refreshes his browser, or restarts the method at this point, I get duplicate records afterwards.

Could anyone please help me out how I can avoid duplicates in my databases cause this method gets called twice by refreshing/reloading/reclicking?

Is it possible to make this method unique per user so I know it is still executing/waiting for response?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Have you considered adding a unique index at the database? Relational databases are build to solve concurrency problems, and sometimes that's their main strength. That way, you don't have to check if the value is there, just `insert` and fail.

Comment: I'm aware of unique index, but that doesn't solve my issue as I only create new records.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix the problem directly in the database instead of the source. You could easily set an database trigger (depends on your DBMS like MySQL, MSSQL) for the INSERT statement.

A good guide to database triggers would be:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i